# Splitting rows to columns in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I have data in a table which looks like:

[image]

I want to split its data and make it look like the following through a sql query in Oracle (without using pivot):

[image]

How can it be done?? is there any other way of doing so without using pivot?

Comment: You need to use either an ANSI-style pivot or the Oracle built-in `PIVOT` function (if you are using 11g or later).  I cannot think of any other way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a pivot query here to get the output you want:

```
SELECT Name,
       MIN(CASE WHEN ID_Type = 'PAN'      THEN ID_No ELSE NULL END) AS PAN,
       MIN(CASE WHEN ID_Type = 'DL'       THEN ID_No ELSE NULL END) AS DL,
       MIN(CASE WHEN ID_Type = 'Passport' THEN ID_No ELSE NULL END) AS Passport
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY Name
```

You could also try using Oracle's built in `PIVOT()` function if you are running version 11g or later.

Comment: Under the hood, Oracle uses `MAX` and `CASE` for PIVOT. Performance wise both are same, it's just less code with PIVOT. You can check that using `EXPAND_SQL_TEXT` procedure provided in 12c.

Answer (score 2):

Since you mention without using PIVOT function, you can try to
**use SQL within group for moving rows onto one line and listagg to display multiple column values in a single column.**

In Oracle 11g, we can use the *listagg* built-in function :

```
select
    deptno,
    listagg (ename, ',') 
    WITHIN GROUP 
    (ORDER BY ename) enames
FROM 
 emp
GROUP BY 
 deptno
```

Which should give you the below result:

```
DEPTNO ENAMES                                            
------ --------------------------------------------------
    10 CLARK,KING,MILLER                                 
    20 ADAMS,FORD,JONES,SCOTT,SMITH                
    30 ALLEN,BLAKE,JAMES,MARTIN,TURNER,WARD
```

You can find all the solution(s) to this problem here:
http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_converting_rows_columns.htm

Comment: Also, keep in mind that listagg return type is VARCHAR2. Consider list size limitation.

Comment: How does this answer OP's question at all? `LISTAGG` is a string aggregation, while OP wants different columns. if you can't use `PIVOT`, then the alternative is `MAX` and `CASE`. Under the hood, Oracle does the same thing with PIVOT. You can check that using `EXPAND_SQL_TEXT` procedure provided in 12c.

Comment: @LalitKumarB: My answer was more based on representing data in horizontal format from the vertical one. This of course comes with a rider that you need to tokenize the column `ENAMES` to fetch the individual values as required.

Answer (score 1):

For Oracle 11g and above, you could use **PIVOT**.

For pre-11g release, you could use **MAX** and **CASE**.

[A common misconception](http://www.orafaq.com/forum/mv/msg/199228/644846/#msg_644846), about `PIVOT` better in terms of performance than the old way of `MAX` and `DECODE`. But, under the hood **PIVOT** is same **MAX + CASE**. You can check it in `12c` where Oracle added **EXPAND_SQL_TEXT** procedure to **DBMS_UTILITY** package.

For example,

```
SQL> variable c clob
SQL> begin
  2      dbms_utility.expand_sql_text(Q'[with choice_tbl as (
  3                      select 'Jones' person,1 choice_nbr,'Yellow' color from dual union all
  4                      select 'Jones',2,'Green' from dual union all
  5                      select 'Jones',3,'Blue' from dual union all
  6                      select 'Smith',1,'Orange' from dual
  7                     )
  8  select  *
  9    from  choice_tbl
 10    pivot(
 11          max(color)
 12          for choice_nbr in (1 choice_nbr1,2 choice_nbr2,3 choice_nbr3)
 13         )]',:c);
 14  end;
 15  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

**Now let's see what Oracle actually does internally:**

```
SQL> set long 100000
SQL> print c

C
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SELECT  "A1"."PERSON" "PERSON",
        "A1"."CHOICE_NBR1" "CHOICE_NBR1",
        "A1"."CHOICE_NBR2" "CHOICE_NBR2",
        "A1"."CHOICE_NBR3" "CHOICE_NBR3"
  FROM  (
         SELECT  "A2"."PERSON" "PERSON",
                 MAX(CASE  WHEN ("A2"."CHOICE_NBR"=1) THEN "A2"."COLOR" END ) "CHOICE_NBR1",
                 MAX(CASE  WHEN ("A2"."CHOICE_NBR"=2) THEN "A2"."COLOR" END ) "CHOICE_NBR2",
                 MAX(CASE  WHEN ("A2"."CHOICE_NBR"=3) THEN "A2"."COLOR" END ) "CHOICE_NBR3"
          FROM  (
                 (SELECT 'Jones' "PERSON",1 "CHOICE_NBR",'Yellow' "COLOR" FROM "SYS"."DUAL" "A7") UNION ALL
                 (SELECT 'Jones' "'JONES'",2 "2",'Green' "'GREEN'" FROM "SYS"."DUAL" "A6") UNION ALL
                 (SELECT 'Jones' "'JONES'",3 "3",'Blue' "'BLUE'" FROM "SYS"."DUAL" "A5") UNION ALL
                 (SELECT 'Smith' "'SMITH'",1 "1",'Orange' "'ORANGE'" FROM "SYS"."DUAL" "A4")
                ) "A2"
          GROUP BY "A2"."PERSON"
       ) "A1"
SQL>
```

Oracle internally interprets the **PIVOT** as **MAX + CASE**.

Answer (score 1):

You're able to create a non-pivot query by understanding what the pivot query will do:

```
select *
from yourTable
pivot
(
  max (id_no)
  for (id_type) in ('PAN' as pan, 'DL' as dl, 'Passport' as passport)
)
```

What the pivot does is `GROUP BY` all columns not specified inside the `PIVOT` clause (actually, just the **name** column), selecting new columns in a subquery fashion based on the aggregations before the `FOR` clause for each value specified inside the `IN` clause and discarding those columns specified inside the `PIVOT` clause.

When I say "subquery fashion" I'm refering to one way to achieve the result got with `PIVOT`. Actually, I don't know how this works behind the scenes. This subquery fashion would be like this:

```
select <aggregation>
from <yourTable>
where 1=1 
  and <FORclauseColumns> = <INclauseValue>
  and <subqueryTableColumns> = <PIVOTgroupedColumns>
```

Now you identified how you can create a query without the `PIVOT` clause:

```
select 
  name,
  (select max(id_no) from yourTable where name = t.name and id_type = 'PAN') as pan,
  (select max(id_no) from yourTable where name = t.name and id_type = 'DL') as dl,
  (select max(id_no) from yourTable where name = t.name and id_type = 'Passport') as passport
from yourTable t
group by name
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CTE's to break the data down and then join them back together to get what you want:

```
WITH NAMES AS (SELECT DISTINCT NAME
                 FROM YOURTABLE),
     PAN AS (SELECT NAME, ID_NO AS PAN
               FROM YOURTABLE
               WHERE ID_TYPE = 'PAN'),
     DL AS (SELECT NAME, ID_NO AS DL
              FROM YOURTABLE
              WHERE ID_TYPE = 'DL'),
     PASSPORT AS (SELECT NAME, ID_NO AS "Passport"
                    FROM YOURTABLE
                    WHERE ID_TYPE = 'Passport')
SELECT n.NAME, p.PAN, d.DL, t."Passport"
  FROM NAMES n
  LEFT OUTER JOIN PAN p
    ON p.NAME = n.NAME
  LEFT OUTER JOIN DL d
    ON d.NAME = p.NAME
  LEFT OUTER JOIN PASSPORT t
    ON t.NAME = p.NAME'
```

Replace `YOURTABLE` with the actual name of your table of interest.

Best of luck.