# How to convert column into rows in oracle 10g

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, pivot

Suppose I have the result of an Oracle sql query:

```
Month   Date
-----   -----
Jan     10
Jan     15
Jan     20
Feb     11
Feb     16
Feb     25
```

I want to display this data in the following format:

```
Jan Jan Jan Feb  Feb   Feb
10  15   20  11  16    25
```

How to write the query?

Comment: Have a look at [PIVOT](https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/pivot-and-unpivot-operators-11gr1)

Comment: What is the criteria for the columns? Will there always be 3 dates per month? Will it always be `Jan` and `Feb` or can it be other months?

Comment: Aleksej, in PIVOT you must use aggregation... But he needs to keep all values =( i'm not sure that PIVOT helps in this case

Comment: @SkyWalker Why not? Do not group, yet aggregate, thus consider all values.

Answer (score 2):

Using **PIVOT**:

```
SQL> WITH sample_data AS(
  2  SELECT 'Jan' mnth, 10 dt FROM dual UNION ALL
  3  SELECT 'Jan' mnth, 15 dt FROM dual UNION ALL
  4  SELECT 'Jan' mnth, 20 dt FROM dual UNION ALL
  5  SELECT 'Feb' mnth, 11 dt FROM dual UNION ALL
  6  SELECT 'Feb' mnth, 16 dt FROM dual UNION ALL
  7  SELECT 'Feb' mnth, 25 dt FROM dual
  8  )
  9  -- end of smaple_data mimicking real table
 10  SELECT *
 11  FROM
 12    (SELECT dt, row_number() OVER(ORDER BY NULL) rn FROM sample_data
 13    ) PIVOT (MAX(dt) FOR (rn)
 14           IN (1 AS Jan_1, 2 AS jan_2, 3 AS Jan_3, 4 AS Feb_1, 5 Feb_2, 6 Feb_3));

     JAN_1      JAN_2      JAN_3      FEB_1      FEB_2      FEB_3
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
        10         15         20         11         16         25
```

[Under the hood](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34453007/3989608) **PIVOT** is same **MAX + CASE**. You can check it in `12c` where Oracle added **EXPAND_SQL_TEXT** procedure to **DBMS_UTILITY** package.

```
SQL> VARIABLE c CLOB
SQL> BEGIN
  2    dbms_utility.expand_sql_text(Q'[WITH sample_data AS(
  3  SELECT 'Jan' mnth, 10 dt FROM dual UNION ALL
  4  SELECT 'Jan' mnth, 15 dt FROM dual UNION ALL
  5  SELECT 'Jan' mnth, 20 dt FROM dual UNION ALL
  6  SELECT 'Feb' mnth, 11 dt FROM dual UNION ALL
  7  SELECT 'Feb' mnth, 16 dt FROM dual UNION ALL
  8  SELECT 'Feb' mnth, 25 dt FROM dual
  9  )
 10  -- end of smaple_data mimicking real table
 11  SELECT *
 12  FROM
 13  (SELECT dt, row_number() OVER(ORDER BY NULL) rn FROM sample_data
 14  ) PIVOT (MAX(dt) FOR (rn)
 15  IN (1 AS Jan_1, 2 AS jan_2, 3 AS Jan_3, 4 AS Feb_1, 5 Feb_2, 6 Feb_3))]',:c);
 16  END;
 17  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

**Now let's see what Oracle actually does internally:**

```
SQL> set long 100000
SQL> print c

C
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SELECT "A1"."JAN_1" "JAN_1",
  "A1"."JAN_2" "JAN_2",
  "A1"."JAN_3" "JAN_3",
  "A1"."FEB_1" "FEB_1",
  "A1"."FEB_2" "FEB_2",
  "A1"."FEB_3" "FEB_3"
FROM
  (SELECT MAX(
    CASE WHE N ("A2"."RN"=1)
      THEN "A2"."DT"
    END ) "JAN_1",
    MAX(
    CASE
      WHEN ("A2"."RN"=2)
      THEN " A2"."DT"
    END ) "JAN_2",
    MAX(
    CASE
      WHEN ("A2"."RN"=3)
      THEN "A2"."DT"
    END ) "JAN_3" ,
    MAX(
    CASE
      WHEN ("A2"."RN"=4)
      THEN "A2"."DT"
    END ) "FEB_1",
    MAX(
    CASE
      WHEN ("A2". "RN"=5)
      THEN "A2"."DT"
    END ) "FEB_2",
    MAX(
    CASE
      WHEN ("A2"."RN"=6)
      THEN "A2"."DT"
    END ) "FEB_3"
  FROM
    (SELECT "A3"."DT" "DT",
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY NULL) " RN"
    FROM (
      (SELECT 'Jan' "MNTH",10 "DT" FROM "SYS"."DUAL" "A10"
      )
    UNION ALL (SE LECT 'Jan' "MNTH",15 "DT" FROM "SYS"."DUAL" "A9")
    UNION ALL
      (SELECT 'Jan' "MNTH",20 "DT" FROM "SYS"."DUAL" "A8"
      )
    UNION ALL
      (SELECT 'Feb' "MNTH",11 "DT" FROM " SYS"."DUAL" "A7"
      )
    UNION ALL
      (SELECT 'Feb' "MNTH",16 "DT" FROM "SYS"."DUAL" "A6"
      )
    UNION ALL
      (SELECT 'Feb' "MNTH",25 "DT" FROM "SYS"."DUAL" "A5"
      )) "A3"
    ) "A2"
  ) " A1"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH dates( month, day ) AS (
  SELECT 'Jan', 10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Jan', 15 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Jan', 20 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Feb', 11 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Feb', 16 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Feb', 25 FROM DUAL
),
ordered_dates( month, day, seq_no ) AS (
  SELECT month,
         day,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY month ORDER BY day )
  FROM   dates
)
SELECT MAX( CASE WHEN month = 'Jan' AND seq_no = 1 THEN day END ) AS "Jan",
       MAX( CASE WHEN month = 'Jan' AND seq_no = 2 THEN day END ) AS "Jan",
       MAX( CASE WHEN month = 'Jan' AND seq_no = 3 THEN day END ) AS "Jan",
       MAX( CASE WHEN month = 'Feb' AND seq_no = 1 THEN day END ) AS "Feb",
       MAX( CASE WHEN month = 'Feb' AND seq_no = 2 THEN day END ) AS "Feb",
       MAX( CASE WHEN month = 'Feb' AND seq_no = 3 THEN day END ) AS "Feb"
FROM   ordered_dates;
```

**Output**:

```
       Jan        Jan        Jan        Feb        Feb        Feb
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
        10         15         20         11         16         25
```