# Query throws "ORA-32033 : unsupported column alias"

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I am unable to run the following query in Toad.

I am getting the error `ORA-32033: unsupported column alias`.

```
WITH
  sample_data( month, day ) AS (
    SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(X,'DD-MM-YY'),'MON') AS month,
           TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(X,'DD-MM-YY'),'DD') AS day
      FROM (SELECT CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('01-05-2015','DD-MM-YY')+(ROWNUM-1),'DY') = 'FRI'
                        THEN TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('01-05-2015','DD-MM-YY')+(ROWNUM-1),'DD-MM-YY')
                        ELSE NULL END AS X
              FROM all_objects
             WHERE ROWNUM < (select (to_date ('01-05-16','dd-MM-yyyy')
                                     - to_date('01-05-15','dd-MM-yyyy') + 1)
                               from dual)
           )
     WHERE X IS NOT NULL;
  ),
  ordered_dates( month, day, seq_no ) AS (
    SELECT month,
           day,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY month ORDER BY day )
      FROM sample_data
  )
SELECT MAX( CASE WHEN month = 'Jan' AND seq_no = 1 THEN day END ) AS "Jan",
       MAX( CASE WHEN month = 'Jan' AND seq_no = 2 THEN day END ) AS "Jan",
       MAX( CASE WHEN month = 'Jan' AND seq_no = 3 THEN day END ) AS "Jan",
       MAX( CASE WHEN month = 'Feb' AND seq_no = 1 THEN day END ) AS "Feb",
       MAX( CASE WHEN month = 'Feb' AND seq_no = 2 THEN day END ) AS "Feb",
       MAX( CASE WHEN month = 'Feb' AND seq_no = 3 THEN day END ) AS "Feb"
  FROM ordered_dates;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What if you remove the `(month, day)` and `(month, day, seq_no)` parts? If that doesn't work, try to trim this down and make it a more minimal example that reproduces. That will make it easier to spot the problem.

Comment: Are you using Oracle 10g?

Comment: Having looked at your earlier question, you probably should have commented on [MTO's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35573388/266304) if that also got this error for you. You should also tag your question with the version you are using so you don't get answers using features that aren't available to you, like `pivot`.

Answer (score 2):

Based on [your previous question title](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35573045/266304), which this question seems to be an extension of, you are using Oracle 10g. The column aliases were not part of the `WITH` clause syntax in Oracle 10g. The [syntax diagram from 10gR2](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_10002.htm#i2161315):

[image]

And the [syntax diagram from 11gR2](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_10002.htm#i2161315):

[image]

The aliases are required for recursive subquery factoring - also added in 11gR2 - and optional otherwise.

For 10g you need to alias the columns as part of the subquery, which you are already doing somewhat redundantly except for `seq_no`, but you also need to remove the aliases from the `WITH ... AS` parts:

```
WITH sample_data AS (
  SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(X,'DD-MM-YY'),'MON') AS month,
         TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(X,'DD-MM-YY'),'DD') AS day 
  FROM
...
),
ordered_dates AS (
  SELECT month,
         day,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY month ORDER BY day ) AS seq_no
  FROM   sample_data
)
...
```

Comment: Thanks I understood.