# How to create an old school Oracle Pivot View

Tags: sql, oracle

Thanks for anyone's ideas about this.
I've had to 'downgrade' to an Oracle database recently where I had an Oracle SQL PIVOT view that worked in 11G, I now have to recreate this pivot the old school 'Group by' method.  Here is my PIVOT view.  Any ideas how I can re-write this view without a PIVOT operator?

```
select JOB_TITLE,
 COUNTRY,
 fte_exp_yrs, 
 fte_alloc,
 first_date
 from ROKPI_HC_V3
pivot (sum(fte_alloc) as mo for (FIRST_DATE) IN
('01-JAN-15' AS JAN_15,
 '01-FEB-15' AS FEB_15,
 '01-MAR-15' AS MAR_15,
 '01-APR-15' AS APR_15,
 '01-MAY-15' AS MAY_15,
 '01-JUN-15' AS JUN_15,
 '01-JUL-15' AS JUL_15,
 '01-AUG-15' AS AUG_15,
 '01-SEP-15' AS SEP_15,
 '01-OCT-15' AS OCT_15,
 '01-NOV-15' AS NOV_15,
 '01-DEC-15' AS DEC_15
 ))
 where JOB_TITLE = 'MANAGER' or JOB_TITLE = 'NONMANAGER' OR JOB_TITLE = 'CPA'
 order by country;
```

Comment: Old school Oracle gurus would recommend you to replace `'01-AUG-15'`with `to_date('01-AUG-15', 'mm-mon-yy', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = American')` to make it resistant to changes of NLS settings of client/server session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'old school' method is to combine the same aggregate function you use in the pivot with a case statement for each value of `first_date`, and group by the other columns:

```
select JOB_TITLE,
 COUNTRY,
 fte_exp_yrs,
 sum(case when FIRST_DATE = '01-JAN-15' then fte_alloc end) AS JAN_15,
 sum(case when FIRST_DATE = '01-FEB-15' then fte_alloc end) AS FEB_15,
 sum(case when FIRST_DATE = '01-MAR-15' then fte_alloc end) AS MAR_15,
 sum(case when FIRST_DATE = '01-APR-15' then fte_alloc end) AS APR_15,
 sum(case when FIRST_DATE = '01-MAY-15' then fte_alloc end) AS MAY_15,
 sum(case when FIRST_DATE = '01-JUN-15' then fte_alloc end) AS JUN_15,
 sum(case when FIRST_DATE = '01-JUL-15' then fte_alloc end) AS JUL_15,
 sum(case when FIRST_DATE = '01-AUG-15' then fte_alloc end) AS AUG_15,
 sum(case when FIRST_DATE = '01-SEP-15' then fte_alloc end) AS SEP_15,
 sum(case when FIRST_DATE = '01-OCT-15' then fte_alloc end) AS OCT_15,
 sum(case when FIRST_DATE = '01-NOV-15' then fte_alloc end) AS NOV_15,
 sum(case when FIRST_DATE = '01-DEC-15' then fte_alloc end) AS DEC_15
from ROKPI_HC_V3
where JOB_TITLE = 'MANAGER' or JOB_TITLE = 'NONMANAGER' OR JOB_TITLE = 'CPA'
group by JOB_TITLE, COUNTRY, fte_exp_yrs
order by country;
```

This is what Oracle does anyway [under the hood with a pivot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35573542/266304).

If `FIRST_DATE` is a date column and not a string - and I hope it is - then you should use an actual date rather than relying on implicit conversion; either with `to_date('01-JAN-15', 'DD-MON-RR')` if you're sure the session date language will always be English, or specifying the NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE in that conversion (as Kordiko shows in a comment), or with a different format mask that isn't NLS-sensitive; or with an ANSI date literal:

```
 sum(case when FIRST_DATE = date '2015-01-01' then fte_alloc end) AS JAN_15,
```

Comment: Truly grateful for your help!  I was definitely way off in my attempts as I was not using a case statement.  Thank you so much!